# Swift 3 - imagePickerController won't update UI

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

Good Day.

Thank you for taking the time to look at my post. The issue that I have is when the picker has selected the image I need a overlay view tobe released from is hidden and the text label to be updated. This however doesnt work from within the "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo" method. Please see my code below it all works except the is hidden and label text setting.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

if let chosenimage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{

  self.LoadingView.isHidden = false
  self.loadingLabel.text = "  Uploading"
  self.loadingSpinner.startAnimating()

  let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenimage, 0.4)! as NSData
  let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

  _loDataPicture._image = imageStr

}

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

APISaveImage()

}
```

Thanks for your time. I would appreciate any help. the above code all works and I can retrieve the image and post it to the server however I cannot invoke the view.ishidden. I have tried moving it into the API method and moving it to after the dismiss

Regards

Comment: Is your spinner or `LoadingView` being covered by something on the UI?
Press the debug view heirarchy button when running your application to determine what is happening.

Comment: Spinner is on top of loading view and loading view has been called in the view will apprear "self.view.bringSubview(toFront: LoadingView)" I will check now. It isnt affected if i call it anywhere else on the same view forinstance on the save button it shows etc